# What does bnum exactly mean in tokyo tyrant

Tags: nosql, tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

1. What does *bnum* exactly mean in tokyo tyrant, can someone explain it with an example?
2. If the size of the tch data file exceeds 2GB, what should I do?